# Get all continuous subsequences of specified size while also wrapping around to the front

Tags: python

Given a list `A` and a size `B`:

```py
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
B = 3
```

Expected output:

```py
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 2], [4, 2, 1], [2, 1, 2]]
```

My [failing] solution:

```py
def sol(A,B):
    return [A[i : i + B] for i in range(B + 1)]
```

My [failing] output:

```py
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 2], [4, 2]]
```

Comment: Check the accepted answer in the duplicate link

Comment: @U12-Forward  without itertools i need

Comment: from itertools import combinations, n = 3
x= [1, 2, 3 , 4, 2]
list(combinations(x, n)) which is wrong because [(1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (1, 3, 2),
 (1, 4, 2),
 (2, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 2),
 (2, 4, 2),
 (3, 4, 2)]

Comment: in above so many elements are there which is not sequence like (1,2,2) (2,3,2)  etc

Comment: What do you mean? `(1, 2, 2)` *is* in `A`... Why would `(1, 2, 2)` *not* be considered one of the subsequences of `A` but `(1, 2, 4)` *is*, according to your post?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "combination" here?

Comment: @abd Do you mean by something like in my answer?

Comment: @U12-Forward yes , but i need to add first two elements  and last one element , also firs element and last two elements

Comment: @ddejohn I want sequence combination, please see the  answer by Code alpha

Comment: Should `[1, 2, 4]` be `[4, 2, 1]` instead? Right now there is no discernible logic behind your desired output.

Comment: @ddejohn its just combination of continuous 3 elements, but i need first element + last 2 elements, first two elements + last element. its kind of cycle

Comment: @ddejohn my bad, i have rectified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight variation on what's been posted, now that I understand what you're asking for:

```py
def sol(x, n):
    wrap = x + x[:(n - 1)]
    return [wrap[i : i + n] for i in range(len(x))]
```

Explanation of `wrap`:

We can use slicing to add a copy of the first `n - 1` elements of `x` to the end of `x`, which simulates "wrapping" back around to the front of the array. Here's an example using letters to make it clearer:

```py
>>> n = 3
>>> x = "abcxyz"
>>> x + x[:(n - 1)]
'abcxyzab'
```

From there, you can take `n`-length slices of `wrap` to simulate "sliding" a window of width `n` across `wrap`:

```py
abcxyz
^^^
abcxyz
 ^^^
abcxyz
  ^^^
abcxyz
   ^^^
abcxyz
^   ^^
abcxyz
^^   ^
```

Since fiddling with indices to wrap around to the front of `x` is tedious, we're simulating it with `wrap`:

```py
abcxyzab
^^^
abcxyzab
 ^^^
abcxyzab
  ^^^
abcxyzab
   ^^^
abcxyzab
    ^^^
abcxyzab
     ^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it as an iterator using `cycle` and `islice` from itertools:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
B = 3

from itertools import cycle,islice

subIter = zip(A,*(islice(cycle(A),i,None) for i in range(1,B)))
for sub in subIter:
    print(sub)

(1, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 4)
(3, 4, 2)
(4, 2, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
```

*Note that this is nothing more than a cute trick, it is not efficient and you should really go with something like ddejohn's solution.*

*or this variant of it:*

```
[ A[i:i+B]+A[:max(0,i+B-len(A))] for i in range(len(A)) ]
```

Another solution would be to use `deque` from collections:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
B = 3

result = [ [*islice(q,q.rotate(-1),B)] 
           for q in [deque(A)] for _ in q.rotate() or A ]

print(result)
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 2], [4, 2, 1], [2, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: I had originally been trying to get `cycle` to work but gave up :D

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give your desired output:

```
def access(x, y, A):
    return [A[i] for i in range(x, y)]

def sol(A, B):
    return [access(i, i+B, A) for i in range(1-B, len(A)-B+1)]
```

Comment: can you explain (1-B, B)

Comment: So, you are looking for 3 numbers on the list which are appearing in a continuous sequence, and you need elements which are also warping on the ends of the list.... 1-B starts from the "4" in the list, and returns 3 elements from there, which also warps around the list (1-B to use negative indices, A[-2] points to 4). B is the ending as the final group needs to end in the last element (2).

Comment: The access function is present as statements like A[-2:1] give an empty list.

Comment: Edit: To make things more general, i have replaced (1-B,B) with (1-B, len(A)-B+1), which will give you the last group, [3, 4, 2], as i ends with 3, so the last access call is access(3, 6).

Comment: This will throw a `NameError` if `A` isn't defined globally.

Comment: I have amended the mistake... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you mean:

```
>>> list(zip(*(A[i:] for i in range(B))))
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 2)]
>>>
```

Comment: This doesn't reflect OP's expected output though. It's hard to answer this question right now because their constraints seem to be inconsistent.

Comment: @ddejohn What I expect is that the OP means this. There is no logic to his desired output.

Comment: its just combination of continuous 3 elements, but i need first element + last 2 elements, first two elements + last element.in addition to [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 2)]    its kind of cycle